# Relative layout for Windows Phone Application using XAML C#

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, xamarin-studio

I am creating Windows phone app and in this app i need to deal with webview control and custom keyboards. I need to use my custom views as keyboard where there is system keyboard is used which is ok but the problem is how do i achieve the Relative layout. Currently in app i have a grid in the page and with 2 rows and I have set the height of first row to "*" and the second row height to 0. In first row there is webiew and in second row there is keyboard. So when the custom keyboard is up the height of second  row is changed from 0 to some value so it appears with keyboard but due to this the height of first row decreases but what i want is that the keyboard should overlap the webview say 6:4 ratio. I want the height of the webview should remain same and the custom keyboard should overlap it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canvas control can be used for such requirement that you have.Please follow this link
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/jj207042(v=vs.105).aspx

Happy Coding :)